# how to render/generate Dynamic HTML content in angular application

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and know mostly theory concepts.

I need to create a web based application with .net and angular perhaps angular version 2,4 or whatever. the angular app html page is dynamic is nature. For example, based on specific user’s login, the html may shows ’n’ number of say Tab controls in panel and even the display ordering of tab on the html page would be different per user based on db saved values. this configuration of tab controls plus other controls like textboxes etc. would come from Database via an seperate .net application on which user can config that for his/her angular website **he may choose ’n’ tab controls along with there** **display order** so **everything would be dynamic like tab controls, there child data pages** etc.

Someone told me that it can be done via Pipes but still I am not getting much of clue how to implement this.

Let me try to be more clear:

1. So from the Database for a specfic user I will fetch the configuration which denotes that whether on a page they need 5 tab controls or 5 textboxes or even the child content ; so then in my angular app i need to create to create such HTML and render.
2. also in 1st point above, from DB i will fetch the display order of elements for specific user on HTML page.
   For example : In Databse , for a specific user a configuration table may denote that he needs tab controls say Home, Index etc on page and display order of Index would be 1st and Home would be 2nd

For another User in DB , a config table may denote that he needs tabs say Home, Index, Salary, employee etc., display order on html page could be salary to be 1st tab n then employee as 2nd tab, home as 3rd etc.

Comment: You question needs to be more specific. Is it how do I order tabs based on a user's preference?

Comment: @Zapacila kindly see the edited question in bold. I am new here, kindly bear with any mistake in posting. In short, its both the order and the tab controls are dynamic in nature and coming via config. each user can see different set of controls on angular application based on their configuration values saved previously in database

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best bet are Dynamic Forms.

There are also some solutions available on github that already generate controls based on a configuration (json, read from db?!). See [ng-dynamic-forms](https://github.com/udos86/ng-dynamic-forms) and [ngx-schema-form](https://github.com/makinacorpus/ngx-schema-form).